# How can I parse a local CSV file with Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, file-upload, upload

I'm trying to use [smarter_csv](https://github.com/tilo/smarter_csv) to parse csv files with my Rails app. But the documentation only explains how to parse a file that already belongs to the app.

I want to parse a file that's stored locally on my computer. So I think I have to upload the file, parse it, and then delete it.

This is how far I got:

```
<%= form_tag({action: :upload}, multipart: true) do %>
  <%= file_field :csv %>
  <%= submit_tag 'Submit' %>
<% end %>
```

So then how can I reference and use the uploaded file in my controller action?

```
def upload
  #save file temporarily to app
  filename = #filename
  #parse file with smarter_csv
  #File.delete(filename)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the file path as a string you need to do the following:

```
filename = params[:csv].path
```

as params[:csv] is a [UploadedFile](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Http/UploadedFile.html) object. You don't need handle the temp file yourself, i.e. storing and deleting it. Rails would do that for you. As per documentation:

> Uploaded files are temporary files whose lifespan is one request. When the object is finalized Ruby unlinks the file, so there is no need to clean them with a separate maintenance task.

Comment: I see. Is it possible to permanently add the file to a given path within the app?